# PrimeNG flexgrid not properly displayed

Tags: angular, primeng

I copied the following sample from PrimeNG website:

```css
"styles": [
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

```html
<h3>MultiLine</h3>
<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="box">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I got the following:
MultiLine
6
6
6
6

can you please explain what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Comment: Have you added ```npm install primeflex --save``` ?
Can you please add a working code snippet?

Comment: Hi Pratik, Yes. I added: npm install primeflex --save

Comment: Found the problem. In the example, there are 2 rows each contains: 6 6. This depends on the screen size.

Comment: It's working good for me, you can check my working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ae52ar Check your node_modules folder, whether Primeflex.css has existed or not.